# How can I write a space character in the console?

Tags: white-space, console

The following code writes in the console, but it doesn't print the space character. How can I force printing space characters?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\message{%
^^J
=======================================
^^J
       [This should be centered]
^^J
=======================================
^^J
}

\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latex format messages use `\space` for one space and `\@spaces` for 4 so

```
 ======================================= 
        [This should be centered] 
 =======================================
```

from

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\message{%
^^J
=======================================
^^J
\@spaces\space\space\space  [This should be centered]
^^J
=======================================
^^J
}

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap it in `\obeyspaces`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

{\obeyspaces\message{%
^^J
=======================================
^^J
       [This should be centered]
^^J
=======================================
^^J
}}

\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It does print the space, but as usual with TeX, if you type several spaces in a row, it collapses them to a single space, and also spaces at the beginning of a line are ignored, so if you just type the spaces there, TeX will ignore them.  There are many ways to do this; one of them is to use `\prg_replicate:nn` to place as many spaces as you want:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \spaces #1
  { \prg_replicate:nn {#1} { ~ } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\message{%
^^J
=======================================
^^J
\spaces{7}[This should be centered]
^^J
=======================================
^^J
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An abstract version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\centermessage}{O{78}m}
 {
  ^^J
  \iow_term:x { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { = } }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \seq_map_tokens:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \__colas_centerline:nn { #1 } }
  \iow_term:x { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { = } }
  ^^J
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__colas_centerline:nn
 {
  \iow_term:x
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 - \str_count:n { #2 } } { 2 } } { ~ }
    #2
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\centermessage{
       [This should be centered] \\ [and also this]
}

\centermessage[50]{
       [This should be centered] \\ [and also this]
}

\end{document}
```

This is what you'll see in the console

```
==============================================================================
                          [This should be centered]
                               [and also this]
==============================================================================
==================================================
            [This should be centered]
                 [and also this]
==================================================
```